# What does this statement mean?

Tags: group-theory

> Let $\phi:G\to H$ be a group homomorphism. Also, let $\psi:H\to H/K$ be a mapping, where $K$ is a subgroup of $H$ (not necessarily normal). The map $G\to G/\phi^{-1}K$ is the restriction of the composition $\psi\circ\phi$ to its image.

What does the last line mean? We know that $\psi\circ\phi$ is a mapping between $G$ and $H/K$. How are we restricting it to its image to create the mapping $G\to G/\phi^{-1}K$?

Comment: $\psi\circ\phi$ does not have to be onto, so if you want to identify its image (which is a set of cosets in $H$) with some set of cosets in $G$ you have to restrict the image, not the domain of the map. The "is" in the mysterious last sentence shouldn't be taken literally, but instead as "can be identified with".

Answer (score 1):

It think what is meant is it's restricted on the  target side, not on the source side: $\psi\,\phi\colon G\rightarrow H/K$ factors through $\,G/\phi^{-1}(K)$ which is in bijection with $\operatorname{im}(\psi\phi)$.